# Почему не работает код риакта?

Tags: reactjs

Не работает код риакта

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Components</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="program"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
var Task=React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function () {
  return: {edit: false}
 },
 edit: function () {
  this.setState ({edit: true})
 },
 save: function () {
  this.setState ({edit: false})
 },
 remove: function () {
  alert("remove");
 },
 rendNorm: function () {
    return (
      <div className="box">
        <div className="text">{this.props.children}</div>
        <button onClick={this.edit} className="btn light">Редактировать</button>
        <button onClick={this.remove} className="btn red">Удалить</button>
      </div>
    );
    },
 rendEdit: function () {
  return (
   <div className="box">
   <textarea defaultValue={this.props.children}></textarea>
   <button className="btn success" onClick={this.save}>Save</button>
   </div>
        );
 },
    render: function() {
    if (this.state.edit) {
      return this.rendEdit ();
    } else {
      return this.rendNorm ();
    }
  }
});


const app=document.getElementById("program");
ReactDOM.render(
 <div className="field">
        <Task>1</Task>
        <Task>2</Task>
        <Task>3</Task>
 </div>, app
 );
    
</script>

<style>
body {
 background-color: #e1e388;
}

.field {
 display: flex;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 25%;
 margin-left: 37.5%;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}

.box {
 border: 2px solid #aaa719;
 background-color: #d4d37f;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 80%;
}

.box:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

button.btn {
 margin-right: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 0.65em;
 color: #fff;
 outline: none;
}

.btn.light {
 background-color: #4eafc9;
 border: 2px solid #2a89a2;
}

.btn.red {
 background-color: #dda66d;
 border: 2px solid #b6821a;
}

.btn.light:hover {
 background-color: #2a89a2;
 border-color: #1d6f85;
}

.btn.red:hover {
 background-color: #b6821a;
 border-color: #946912;
}    
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы вопрос не правильно задаете. Просто говорите `почему этот код не работает`. Можете объяснить что оно должно сделать, после чего перестала работать. Все по порядку и подробно.

Comment: И зачем вы используете старые библиотеки?

Comment: Почему этот самый же вопрос повторяется каждый день?